# How can I exlude some area in my card so that it is not clickable?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have a mat-card element which is clickable and it navigates when we click it. However the card has some buttons like `edit` `delete` and `refresh`. When I click the delete button, the page navigates and the item is deleted.

I want the page not to navigate as I click on those buttons.

The html boilerplate is as below:

```html
<mat-card
  *ngIf="team$ | async as team"
  [routerLink]="[team?.id]"
  [ngClass]="{ passive: (loadingByDelete$ | async) === loadingState.Pending }"
>
  <mat-card-title>{{ team?.name }}</mat-card-title>
  <mat-card-content>
    <h3>Tor</h3>

    <mat-spinner
      *ngIf="(loadingByLoadTeam$ | async) === loadingState.Pending"
      color="accent"
      mode="indeterminate"
      [diameter]="100"
    ></mat-spinner>
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions align="end">
    <ng-container *ngIf="team$ | async as team">
      <a mat-button [routerLink]="['/teams', 'edit', team?.id]"> Edit </a>

      <button
        mat-raised-button
        [disabled]="
          (loadingByLoadTeam$ | async) === loadingState.Pending || (loadingByDelete$ | async) === loadingState.Pending
        "
        (click)="deleteTeam()"
      >
        Delete
      </button>

      <button
        mat-icon-button
        color="primary"
        (click)="loadTeam()"
        [disabled]="
          (loadingByLoadTeam$ | async) === loadingState.Pending || (loadingByDelete$ | async) === loadingState.Pending
        "
      >
        <mat-icon>refresh</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </ng-container>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: so remove [routerLink]="[team?.id]" from mat-card

Comment: How could be then card clickable? @MarkHomer

Comment: @CelalettinTurgut it wouldnt :) you could add another button

Comment: event.stopPpropogation() stops an event from bubbling. But is your code legal or have you got nested anchor/button elements?

Comment: I have 3 button elements nested in `<ng-container>` @AHaworth

Comment: a cheat way is using  `[routerLink]="[team?.id]"` on `mat-card-content` tag not `mat-card`